# Fill fields depending on a data.frame

Tags: json, r, shiny

Here is my actual code :

ui.R

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(


  titlePanel("Visualition de cube"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("choixCube", "Choix du cube :", choices = NULL),
      selectInput("choixDim", "Choix des dimensions", choices = NULL),
      selectInput("choixMes", "Choix des mesures", choices = NULL)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("distPlot")
    )
  )
))
```

server.R

```
library(shiny)
library(jsonlite)
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

json <- fromJSON("./init.json")
cubes <- json$cube %>% setDT()

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  observe({
    updateSelectInput(session, "choixCube",choices = cubes$name)
  })


  test <- reactive({
    if(!is.null(input$choixCube)){
      cubes[name == input$choixCube, dim][[1]]
    }
  })
  observe({
    updateSelectInput(session, "choixDim", choices = test)
  })
})
```

As you can see, I am loading an init JSON file that contain information about the data that I load. I would like to fill the field "choixDim" with the list in the column "dim" in the dataframe of the json filter.

How can i do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, it is best to separate the loading of the json and libraries in a separate global.R file. Anything loaded in here is also available in the ui. Note that I have changed the json file to a simple data.frame create a working example.

ui.R

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(


  titlePanel("Visualition de cube"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("choixCube", "Choix du cube :", choices = NULL),
      selectInput("choixDim", "Choix des dimensions", choices = json$dim),
      selectInput("choixMes", "Choix des mesures", choices = NULL)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("distPlot")
    )
  )
))
```

server.R

```
cubes <- json$cube %>% setDT()

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  observe({
    updateSelectInput(session, "choixCube",choices = cubes$name)
  })

  test <- reactive({
    if(!is.null(input$choixCube)){
      cubes[name == input$choixCube, dim][[1]]
    }
  })


})
```

global.R

```
library(shiny)
library(jsonlite)
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

json <- data.frame(dim= c("dim1","dim2","dim3"))
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Brilliant, glad I could help. If you could please accept my answer that would be great!